# Error Number 11 in msgget()

Tags: message-queue, system-calls

I am using system V message queues. When i used **msgget** system call, i got error number 11.

That error is coming only some number of times like 4 to 5.

After that, it succeeded.

What is that means, and Why it came? And how to handle that error message?

Comment: What kernel? Linux, I would presume? And which version of the kernel?

Comment: Also, please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Error Number 11 is **EAGAIN**.

When ever the queue becomes full, then i am getting this message. That means, resource is temporarily unavailable, So, please try again.